# I am looking for a tool that would batch process EAN13 numbers, with outputs to an image file

Tags: windows, open-source, automation, productivity, barcode

I am trying to save weeks of copy and pasting between excel sheets and my EAN13 tool. Is there a bit of **free** software out there, that would allow me to take a list of numbers (CSV, new line, etc) and process them into correct **EAN13** bar codes, then save the bar codes as individual images in a single process?

I have no requirements on what type of image file it outputs, not do I really care what format the tool comes in. I'd just be happy with something that works, be it CLI or with an GUI.

I am using a windows system ATM, but have access to a linux one if needed.

Thank you in advance!

Dev

Comment: Did you try [Zint Barcode Generator](https://sourceforge.net/projects/zint/)? It looks like you can import a sequence and then export barcodes: https://a.fsdn.com/con/app/proj/zint/screenshots/zint_26_shap5.png/max/max/1

Comment: It was one of the first I looked at. I went back to it, just in case I missed something.

At this point, I am not sure if I am being a fool or not. But it does have an EAN setting.

However; when I use it, it's missing a few numbers end. This doesn't allow me to make the codes I'd need. I have also researched the EAN14 setting it has, but I am still unsure if they are interchangeable. 

as it stands, it looks like the EAN14 has some additional meta data or something like that. I wouldn't like to push out a few 1000 barcodes and hope they work. 

I hope you understand my concern.

Comment: please clarify ”*it's missing a few numbers end*“. – BTW It doesn't look like EAN-14 exists: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Trade_Item_Number

Comment: [Here](https://i.imgur.com/JKHNSN0.png) you can see that Zint has a setting for EAN14... It might be new, it might be upcoming... I simply don't know. But the link you provided, certainly clears a few things up on the matter.

Comment: Missing numbers. When I put in the numbers I'd like converted to EAN, it is missing at least 3 on the end. You simply can't add any more. [here you can see](https://i.imgur.com/E9G6iE1.png)